# Vagrant fails to load because grub2 waits for kernel selection after ungraceful shutdown

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Vagrant box with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Sometimes after forcing a shutdown (e.g. because the machine became unresponsive) the vagrant box fails to boot the next time.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
```

The preview screenshot in Virtualbox suggests that the box hangs at the grub stage, forever waiting for a user input to select the kernel.

[image: Screenshot of Vagrantbox stuck at grub]

So every time this occurs, I set `vb.gui = true` in the Vagrantfile, restart the machine and select the kernel to boot manually. The interesting thing is that after selecting the kernel once, subsequent headless starts again just work fine - until the next ungraceful machine shutdown.

My questions is: Is there a more elegant way that does not require manual intervention to prevent that the vagrant box hangs at the grub kernel selection screen after a forced shutdown?

Answer (score 4):

First, get the machine id

```
# Before v1.1
# MACHINE_ID=$(awk -F\" '{print $6}' .vagrant)
# After v1.1
MACHINE_ID=$(cat .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id)
```

Power off the VM

```
VBoxManage controlvm ${MACHINE_ID} poweroff
```

Then boot the machine with a GUI console

```
VBoxManage startvm ${MACHINE_ID}
```

Wait for it to boot, login, run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

When successful, shut it down

```
VBoxManage controlvm ${MACHINE_ID} poweroff
```

And after this, vagrant up will just boot your VM normally

[Source](http://kvz.io/blog/2013/07/25/fix-vagrant-box-hanging-at-boot/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this answer. However, this solution also contains a lot of manual steps and I wondered if there exists some "automatic" way to fix this.

Comment: I don't think there's a grub specific option to add to your Vagrantfile to prevent this behaviour. But once fixed, it should not happen again.

Comment: After it boots successfully you can add GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0 to /etc/default/grub to prevent this from happening again (and run update-grub after adding that line). This will tell grub to boot normally after a crash instead of waiting around for user input to choose recovery options which can't be answered since the VM is headless.

Answer (score 1):

Add to `/etc/default/grub` of your box:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

And run:

```
sudo update-grub
```